# Install Drupal 8.x PostgreSQL

Tags: drupal-8

Tell me, how to install Drupal 8.1.9 or 8.2.0 with PostgreSQL? Interestingly, in earlier versions, when the installation was attended by a selection of PostgreSQL. In newer versions this is even no mention

Answer (score 1):

Alternative database engines such as SQLite and PostgreSQL are still available in Drupal 8. However, only the available engines are shown.

If you install the correct PDO module for your PHP environment (e.g. php70-pdo-pgsql) you should have that engine available to you:

[image: Screenshot of installation script]

You can also use phpinfo() to tell if PostgreSQL support is correctly enabled. You will find the following statement there if it is:
PDO Driver for PostgreSQL => enabled

Answer (score 0):

remove the commented code `extension=pdo_pgsql` from php.ini file and then start the setup you will see the `postgreSQL` database option